# R-symmetry constants in $\mathcal{N}=4$ SYM in Yukawa terms

Tags: supersymmetry, lie-algebra, yang-mills

The expression for $\mathcal{N}=4$ SYM in the Lorentz covariant form involves structure constants of $SU(4)$ R-symmetry group in the Yukawa terms (formula 3.1 from here https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0201253):
$$
g C_{i}^{ab} \lambda_{a} [X^{i}, \lambda_{b}]
+ 
g \bar{C}_{iab} \bar{\lambda}^{a} [X^{i}, \bar{\lambda}^{b}] 
$$
And these structure constants are said to originate straightforwardly from the dimensional reduction of $\mathcal{N}=1$ SYM from 10d to 4d.

However, there are no such constants in Van der Waerden notation (dotted/undotted), as shown in this paper - https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.3871:
$$
\phi_{ij} \{\chi_{\alpha}^{i}, \chi^{j \alpha}\} + \phi_{ij} \{\chi_{\dot{\alpha}}^{i}, \chi^{j \dot{\alpha}}\}
$$
Here $\alpha, \dot{\alpha}$ are the spinor indices.
The raise and lowering of the $R$-symmetry indices, if I am not mistaken is performed via $\varepsilon$-symbol, and It seems so far not evident, that this structure constant can be so easily absorbed.
Where have the structure constants gone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution. It is a matter of how one defines the scalar field in $\mathcal{N} = 4$ SYM. In this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9908171 (page 43) this constant is absorbed into the scalar field:
$$
\phi^{i} = \frac{1}{2} t_{AB}^{i} \phi^{AB}
$$